# using IN instruction crashes the x86 program

Tags: assembly, io, x86, masm32

I am trying to write a delay timer using port 61H (PB4) and using `MASM` run it on a Windows XP on virtual machine. However, when the code runs the `IN` instruction, it crashes the program, no matter which port is called.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall


include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc
include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data
msg1 db "text 1  ", 0
msg2 db "text 2", 0
msg3 db "text 2", 0

.code
start proc

invoke crt_printf, offset msg1
push cx

call waitf
pop cx

invoke crt_printf, offset msg2

invoke crt_scanf, offset msg3
invoke ExitProcess,0

start endp


waitf proc near
    mov cx, 33144
    push ax
    waitf1:
        in al, 61h
        and al, 10h
        cmp al, ah  
        je waitf1   
        mov ah, al
        loop waitf1
        pop ax  
        ret
waitf endp

end start
```

I can not understand why the computer can not get data from the port 61h.

Comment: In protected mode ports are privileged. You either need permissions or have to be in kernel mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computer **can** get data from I/O port but only if it runs in real mode or in [ring 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717016/what-are-ring-0-and-ring-3-in-the-context-of-operating-systems), which is reserved for kernel and device drivers.
In native DOS you can read whichever I/O port you like, and some well-known ports can be read/written even when the realmode program runs in simulator (NTVDM, DosBox).

But as you have chosen Windows protected-mode executable, this won't work.
Invoke WinAPI function  [Sleep(dwMilliseconds)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) instead.

Comment: You can have IOPL=0 without CPL=0 (ring 0).  e.g. Linux's [`iopl` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/iopl.2.html).  x86 also has hardware support for a per-port access permission map that lets the kernel grant user-space permission for some specific low port numbers to a user-space process (Linux [`ioperm` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioperm.2.html)).  (I assume that's why Jester didn't try to be specific about what permissions are required for `in` in a comment, because it's non-trivial to describe all the ways).

Comment: Agreed that doing any of this for a delay timer is crazy in user-space under a multi-tasking OS, though!

Comment: Found more detail about how ioperm works: there's a permission bitmap in the TSS: [How does Linux handles the I/O Permission Bitmap in the TSS structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55501443)